# Expandable ListView is very slow in android os

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollbar, expandablelistview

My expandable `listview` scroll very slow and take a while when I click on the parent category until I see the `child` view.

Group List Activity:

```
public class GroupsListActivity extends Activity {

    String loggedUserId = Model.getInstance().getLoggedUserId();

    List<String> groupsList;
    static ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    HashMap<String, List<Group>> groupCategories = new HashMap<String, List<Group>>();
    static ProgressBar spinner;
    static TextView textLoading;
    ImageButton createCategoryButton;
    static Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set layout for this activity
        setContentView(R.layout.expandable_list);

        // Set actionbar title
        getActionBar().show();
        getActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#fffffff'>Groups</font>"));

        if (loggedUserId != null)
            Log.d("TAG", "My Groups for user ID: " + loggedUserId);

        // Connect between buttons to layout id
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_list);
        spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        createCategoryButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.createCategory);
        textLoading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLoading);

        // Loading data to expandable group list asynchronously
        AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap<String, List<Group>>> task = new AsyncTask<String, String, HashMap<String, List<Group>>>() {
            @Override
            protected HashMap<String, List<Group>> doInBackground(String... params) {
                return DataProvider.getInfo();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, List<Group>> listHashMap) {
                super.onPostExecute(listHashMap);

                // Setting adapter and creating group list
                groupCategories = listHashMap;
                groupsList = new ArrayList<String>(groupCategories.keySet());
                adapter = new Adapter(GroupsListActivity.this, groupCategories, groupsList, GroupsListActivity.this);
                expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                // Hide spinner after loading
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        };
        task.execute();

        // Setting listener for group click
        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int parentPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // After selecting a group on row - open contacts list for this group
                expandableListView.setEnabled(false);
                openContactListForGroup(groupCategories.get(groupsList.get(parentPosition)).get(childPosition).getGroupID());
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Setting listener for create group click
        createCategoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createCategoryButton.setEnabled(false);
                onCategoryCreate(GroupsListActivity.this, createCategoryButton);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_actionbar_groups, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_create:
                onCreate();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_search:
                onSearch();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_favorites:
                onFavorites();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                onSettings();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Menu methods
    private void onCreate() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Create button was pressed");
        Intent i = new
                Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                CreateGroupActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_right);
    }

    private void onSearch() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Search button was pressed");
        Intent i = new
                Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SearchActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_right);
    }

    private void onFavorites() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Favorites button was pressed");
        Intent i = new
                Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                FavoritesListActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_right);
    }

    private void onSettings() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Settings button was pressed");

        // Settings activity
        Intent i = new
                Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SettingsActivity.class);

        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_right);
    }

    // Methods to handle action buttons
    private void onCategoryCreate(final Activity activity, final ImageButton createCategoryButton) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        createCategoryButton.setEnabled(true);

        final String title = "Create a new category";
        String message = "Type a name for your new category";

        // Set dialog edit_text
        final EditText categoryNameTextView = new EditText(activity);
        categoryNameTextView.setHint("Type your category name");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        categoryNameTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        builder.setView(categoryNameTextView);

        // Set dialog title and message
        if (title != null)
            builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#dc1c1c'>" + title + "</font>")).setMessage(message);

        // Set dialog buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String newCategoryName = categoryNameTextView.getText().toString();

                // Check if contains only spaces
                if (!(newCategoryName.trim().length() > 0))
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Type at least 1 letter to create the category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Check if category name already exists
                else if (groupsList.contains(newCategoryName))
                    Toast.makeText(activity, newCategoryName + " already exist. Please type another category name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                else {
                    // Create a new category in server and add user to a sample group
                    adapter.getCategoriesList().add(newCategoryName);
                    adapter.getGroupsList().put(newCategoryName, Collections.<Group>emptyList());

                    // Update adapter and show toast to user
                    GroupsListActivity.updateAdapter();
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "You created " + newCategoryName + " category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(
                "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.edit);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void openContactListForGroup(String groupId) {
        // Contacts List activity
        Intent i = new
                Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ContactsListActivity.class);

        // Pass to details activity the logged group id and start activity
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("groupId", groupId);
        i.putExtras(b);

        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_out_right, R.animator.slide_in_right);
    }

    // Static methods to use from other activities
    public static void updateAdapter() {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Hide spinner after adapter finish the update
        expandableListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void addGroupToList(String groupId) {
        Model.getInstance().getGroup(groupId, new Model.groupReturnedListener() {
            @Override
            public void addGroupToLocal(Group group) {
                // Add group to category Others in Group List Activity
                if (adapter.getGroupsList().get("Others").size() == 0) {
                    // Add group to empty list
                    List<Group> list = new LinkedList<Group>();
                    list.add(group);
                    adapter.getGroupsList().put("Others", list);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // Add group to an existing list
                    adapter.getGroupsList().get("Others").add(group);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void removeGroupFromList(String groupId) {
        int position = -1;

        // Get category position
        String oldCategoryName = Model.getInstance().getCategoryNameByGroupId(groupId);
        List<Group> data = adapter.getGroupsList().get(oldCategoryName);

        // Search for group position
        for (Group group : data) {
            if (group.getGroupID().equals(groupId)) {
                position = data.indexOf(group);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Groups was found
        if (position != -1) {
            data.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public static void updateGroupFromList(Group group) {
        int position = -1;

        // Get category position
        String oldCategoryName = Model.getInstance().getCategoryNameByGroupId(group.getGroupID());
        List<Group> data = adapter.getGroupsList().get(oldCategoryName);

        // Search for group position
        for (Group groupIterator : data) {
            if (groupIterator.getGroupID().equals(group.getGroupID())) {
                position = data.indexOf(groupIterator);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Groups was found
        if (position != -1) {
            data.remove(position);
            data.add(group);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    // Other methods
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        expandableListView.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        ExitDialog exitDialog = new ExitDialog(GroupsListActivity.this);
        exitDialog.show();
    }
}
```

This is the activity of the Adapter where I load the expandable `listview` :

```
   @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        final String categoryName = (String)getGroup(parent);

        ParentViewHolder pHolder = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            pHolder = new ParentViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_parent, parentView, false);

            // Connect between buttons to layout id
            pHolder.categoryNameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
            pHolder.editCategory = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editCategory);
            pHolder.deleteCategory = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteCategory);
            convertView.setTag(pHolder);
        }
        else {
            pHolder = (ParentViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Hide edit and delete button for category name Others
        if(categoriesList.get(parent).equals("Others")){
            pHolder.editCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pHolder.deleteCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        else {
            pHolder.editCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pHolder.deleteCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // Set category name on row
        pHolder.categoryNameTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        pHolder.categoryNameTextView.setText(categoryName + ": " + getChildrenCount(parent));

        // Set edit category button listener
        final ParentViewHolder finalPHolder = pHolder;
        pHolder.editCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalPHolder.editCategory.setEnabled(false);
                editCategoryName(activity, finalPHolder.categoryNameTextView.getText().toString().toString().split(": ")[0], finalPHolder.editCategory, parent);
            }
        });

        // Set delete category button listener
        pHolder.deleteCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalPHolder.deleteCategory.setEnabled(false);
                deleteCategory(activity, categoryName, finalPHolder.deleteCategory);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int parent, final int child, boolean lastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        final Group group = (Group)getChild(parent, child);

        ChildViewHolder cHolder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            cHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_child, parentView, false);

            // Connect between buttons to layout id
            cHolder.groupImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupImage);
            cHolder.groupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
            cHolder.moveCategory = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.moveCategory);
            cHolder.groupFavoritesButton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupFavorites);
            cHolder.groupLeaveGroupButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupLeave);
            cHolder.groupImageProgressbar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupImageProgressBar);
            convertView.setTag(cHolder);
        } else {
            cHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Set group name on row
        cHolder.groupName.setText(group.getName());

        // Load group image
        cHolder.groupImageProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final ChildViewHolder finalHolder = cHolder;
        Model.getInstance().getGroupImage(group.getImageName(), new Model.LoadImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Bitmap imageBmp) {
                finalHolder.groupImage.setImageBitmap(imageBmp);
                finalHolder.groupImageProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                finalHolder.groupImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        // Set move category button listener
        cHolder.moveCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalHolder.moveCategory.setEnabled(false);
                showDialogMoveCategory(activity, group.getGroupID(), finalHolder.moveCategory);
            }
        });


        // After click on group image - open profile for this group
        cHolder.groupImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onGroupSelected(group.getGroupID());
            }
        });

        // Setting favorite Button Image
        boolean isFavorite = Model.getInstance().groupIsFavorite(loggedUserId, group.getGroupID());

        if(isFavorite)
            cHolder.groupFavoritesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.favorites_on);
        else
            cHolder.groupFavoritesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.favorites_off);

        // Setting favorite Button Action
        cHolder.groupFavoritesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Add group to favorites
                if (!Model.getInstance().groupIsFavorite(loggedUserId, group.getGroupID())) {
                    finalHolder.groupFavoritesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.favorites_on);
                    Toast.makeText(activity,
                            "The group " + group.getName() + " was added to favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Model.getInstance().changeFavoriteStatus(loggedUserId, group.getGroupID(), "true");

                } else {
                    // Delete group from favorites
                    finalHolder.groupFavoritesButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.favorites_off);
                    Toast.makeText(activity,
                            "The group " + group.getName() + " was removed from favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Model.getInstance().changeFavoriteStatus(loggedUserId, group.getGroupID(), "false");
                }
            }
        });

        // After click on group action - leave group
        cHolder.groupLeaveGroupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalHolder.groupLeaveGroupButton.setEnabled(false);
                showDialogLeaveGroup(activity, "Are you sure ?", "This action will remove yourself from the group " + group.getName(), group.getGroupID(), parent, child);
                finalHolder.groupLeaveGroupButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

The loading image method:

```
public void getGroupImage(final String imageName, final LoadImageListener listener) {
        AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> task = new AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                Bitmap bmp = loadImageFromFile(imageName);              //first try to find the image on the device
                //  Bitmap bmp = null;
                if (bmp == null) {                                      //if image not found - try downloading it from parse
                    bmp = modelParse.getGroupImage(imageName);
                    if (bmp != null)
                        saveImageToFile(bmp, imageName);    //save the image locally for next time *****
                }
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = scaleDown(bmp, 200, true);
                return scaledBitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                listener.onResult(result);
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }

 private void saveImageToFile(Bitmap imageBitmap, String imageFileName) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, imageFileName + ".jpg"));
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap loadImageFromFile(String fileName) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(dir, fileName + ".jpg"));
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give a general (abstract) idea about listviews and adapters which should help you figure out the wrong parts yourself.

**The whole purpose of the adapter is to display the correct data for the corresponding list item and do as little other job as possible**. In this process, anything that is related to data manipulation is requiring CPU cycles that will cause lags and slow scrolling.

Specifically, android apps should run at a smooth 60 frames-per-second and each frame should take no longer than 16.6 milliseconds to render in order to achieve this 60FPS rate. So if you are creating extra load for the CPU it may come on the account of frame rendering and from here the path to lags in rendering is short.

What am I saying - there are probably some methods in your adapter that are manipulating data on the spot, synchronously and it's taxing the CPU. The adapter should take represent the data that is ALREADY prepared for display and show it in the correct view. An example of performance issues might be as easy as using `String.replace()` method every time for every view or another bad example will be loading images Synchronously instead of Asynchronously.

Comment: Now, I used all my methods that receive data from the model synchronously. I just started and I plan to make all the methods asynchronouly in the future. Are you saying that after I change these methods I will get a smooth scroll?? becuase If I init a list of 1000 objects in the adapter, without getting data from a model and server It looks great!!!
If you answers is yes, can you tell if there are other issues?? because I used a viewHolder as @Gabe Sechan told me but I don't know if I did it correctly. And please can you tell me how I load images with viewHolder? Btw I'm from ashdod :)

Comment: Ahah nice to meet here :). Yes it is what I'm saying -thenetwork call should absolutly not happen in the adapter, it should happen before and whatever was downloaded should be inside the model before you pass the model to the adapter. Second - not all method should be async but the heavy ones like loading images should

Comment: Can you take a look? I added the activity code and the loading images methods where I load asynchronously the data with my DataProvider. Then I init my adapter. Now I can see on the app a spinner until the adapter get the information and then update the view (it's more fluid than before. I had before a black screen until the data is showing). But I dont have a fluid list when I scroll or I try to expand a category. Can you help and tell me what to change ? maybe is the images or something else...

Answer (score 0):

I see two major issues with performance.

First, your use of findViewById everywhere.  You're walking the entire view tree doing that.  That's why people use ViewHolder patterns or custom view patterns.  If you ever use findViewById more than once per view in the lifetime of your app, you're doing it wrong.

Second, you're allocating new objects every time the user scrolls.  Don't.  Use a ViewHolder or custom view pattern to reuse the same `OnClickListener`'s for all scroll events, creating them only once per row and updating the values as needed.  If you ever make an object in your getView, other than when convertView is null, you're being inefficient.

Comment: I red about it just now, Can you provide an efficient tutorial ?. If I get it right,  I should init the buttons (findViewById) just on the first loading and then use the "old" information that I get before i scrolled??

Comment: That's the basics.  Same with any Listener classes-  create them on first load and reuse them (changing any internal state as needed) on scroll.

Comment: Look my question, I added to the getView method the viewHolder but is still slow

Comment: Look my question, I added to the code the viewHolder but is still slow. I tried in a simple list view 1000 objects and it's working. But on the expandable list is still slow. What can I do to improve (I red something about using collection inside viewHolder to save the images. Now I load from server and save locally first time and then get the image back from file, But as you see is without async task)